# file created in s3 bucket but file is empty

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

while uploading a file from the browser. filename is created in the s3 bucket but the content of the file is empty.

```
    @app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            file = request.files['file']
            file.filename = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") ## filename=TIMESTAMP

            # Read the contents of the file
            file_contents = file.open()
            s3.Object('mybucket', file.filename).put(file_contents)

            # Connect to s3 bucket
            s3=boto3.resource('s3')
        return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

changing this fixed it:

```
file_contents = file.open() ---> file_contents = file.read()

s3.Object('mybucket', file.filename).put(file_contents) --> s3.Object('mybucket', file.filename).put(Body=file_contents)
```